# How to handle R kernel tibble in Jupyter lab .ipynb file to display limited row results?

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, tibble, jupyter-irkernel, tidymodels

I am trying using R Kernel in jupyter lab and getting 1000's of rows or more displaying when results are tibble, this makes my browser crash sometimes.

How do i limit these so that it doesn't make my browser crash and works as smoothly as in Rstudio ?

**I am using below versions:**

*jupyter lab: Version 2.2.6*

*R: R version 4.0.3*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a proper solution but a way around that I tried is to `pipe` the results to `print` and mention number of rows there: `validaton_splits %>% print(n=1)`.

[image]